# What's the polyfill for logb in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to use something like [`logb` from C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/logb/) but Google searches turn up [absolutely nothing useful](https://www.google.com/search?ei=M1X1WfrmI6OwjwSxooa4Cg&q=javascript%20logb&oq=javascript%20logb&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1l3j0i13i30k1l6j0i13i10i30k1.5214.5362.0.5603.2.2.0.0.0.0.109.172.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.63....0.niNm78__dKo) and I'm having trouble understanding how to replicate the function based on that C++ document.

Does anyone know how to make a polyfill or equivalent function for JS?

Answer (score 1):

From the document you linked

> Returns the logarithm of |x|, using FLT_RADIX as base for the
>   logarithm.
>
> On most platforms, FLT_RADIX is 2, and thus this function is
>   equivalent to log2 for positive values.

So you just need to compute whats the `log2(|x|)`.

```
Math.log(Math.abs(x))/Math.log(2)
```

---

Logarithmic functions have a base, the most common one is 10 since we work in a base 10 numeric system. Common bases for computers is a base 2 since it works in a binary system. Converting bases can be simply done by working with this formula.

> Log<sub>b</sub>(x) = Log<sub>v</sub>(x) / Log<sub>v</sub>(b)

Simply take the `Log(x)` in any base you want (10 for instance) and divide it by the `Log(b)`.

Heres a relevant link about it:

http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/change-of-base-formula-for-logarithms/a/logarithm-change-of-base-rule-intro

You might right a function like:

```
// get the log value of x using base b
function logb(x, b) {
  return Math.log(x)/Math.log(b);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, in [the context I'm trying to replicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46996648/5536767), the person inputs two numbers to `logb` like [this](https://gist.github.com/viziionary/6bc20c1a459ee960255abc6a670125b9) maybe you could explain how I could make a `logb` version which accepts two inputs?

Comment: @Viziionary the gist you linked to doesn't show the function, and the original one doesn't seem to say anything about a 2nd param. However I updated my answer with what *I think* the 2nd param would be and about it.